# what are the use cases for IgnorePointer widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have seen the `IgnorePointer` widget in Flutter, but the use cases seem very rare. Can someone happen to elaborate on this with some more use cases and examples?

Answer (score 0):

For example, I'm creating a custom widget which looks like the following one.

```
Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
      GestureDetector(
         child: Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            width: 100,
            height: 100
         ),
         onTap: () {
            print('clicked');
         },
      ),
      Container(
         color: Colors.green,
         width: 50,
         height: 50,
      ),
   ],
),
```

Which looks like:

[image: Example Image]

In this widget, I've have added a tap functionality to the amber colored container. But if user taps on the green area, the background container won't receive any touches. Because that touch will be consumed by the green container. For me, the green one was some-kind of a design element and I don't want it to block the touches. So in this case, I can wrap the green one with [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) and it won't intercept my touches any more.

```
IgnorePointer(
   child: Container(
             color: Colors.green,
             width: 50,
             height: 50,
           ),
   ignoring: true,
),
```